Clay tile roof bedding and pointing
Just moved moved to a new home, built in 1996. Had a roofer replace a few cracked tiles. He recommended to put cement/mortar under hips and ridges. I looked at several homes around the neighborhood and none have any mortar around the sides. Is it needed, should the original builders have installed the ridges with bedding and pointing? See pic.Should I go with the roofers recommendation?

Exposed roofing sheathing means the tiles are not doing their job. You should follow your roofer's recommendations, particularly if you receive rain regularly.
